# Server error when attempting to read report names from SSRS server

Tags: c#, web-services, reporting-services

I am attempting to read the report names from an SSRS server into a list.  I have created the web reference without a problem and I can reach the web service through IE.

I receive a 503 Error: Server Unavailable when executing the code. I thought it might be a permissions issue but have used admin creds to no avail.  The exception occurs at line "items = service.ListChildren("/BRADS", true).

```
    ReportService.ReportingService2005 service;

    public ReportsRepository()
    {
        service = new ReportService.ReportingService2005();
        //string rptUserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rptUser"];
        //string rptPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rptPwd"];
        //System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(rptUserID, rptPassword);
        //service.Credentials = cred;
        service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
    }


    IEnumerable<DataModels.ReportingService> IReportsRepository.GetReports()
    {
        CatalogItem[] items;
        DataModels.ReportingService rpt = null;
        List<DataModels.ReportingService> lstReports = null;
        try
        {
            items = service.ListChildren("/BRADS", true);
            if (items != null)
            {
                lstReports = new List<DataModels.ReportingService>();
                foreach (CatalogItem item in items)
                {
                    if (item.HiddenSpecified == false && item.Type == ItemTypeEnum.Report)
                    {
                        rpt = new DataModels.ReportingService();
                        rpt.ReportName = item.Name;
                        rpt.ReportPath = item.Path;
                        rpt.Category = item.Description;
                    }
                    lstReports.Add(rpt);
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return lstReports;
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: is `/BRADS` is that a location on the web..? if so try changing it to `~/BRADS`

Comment: /BRADS is the project name on the server

Answer (score 0):

You need to set service.Url property to valid RS2005 endpoint (ie. `http://servername/reportserver/reportservice2005.asmx` )

Comment: I have the URL set correctly.  I can even access the URL through IE without an issue.